# UK immigration rules v3.2b

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals

Could anyone give me some insight into this section of the immigration rules please? Does this refer to UK only as an immediate refusal or does it also refer to deportation orders from USA?

**V 3.2 An application will be refused if:**

(b) **the applicant is currently the subject of a deportation order or a decision to make a deportation order.**

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Uk only. Your immigration offense in USA for example does not apply in UK and doesn’t lead to automatic refusal.

It may be reviewed as part of your whole immigration profile to evaluate how well you adhere to immigration rules and lawful you are. Obviously it is not a positive.

REFERENCES

General knowledge plus two news articles of people deported from USA who are now students in UK.